# Azure API Management - multiple Azure regions deployment, disable a region?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I want to setup an Azure API Management service in **1 active and 1 passive regions - Eg: Active : West & Passive : East.** However both the regions should be in sync always though the secondary location will be disabled.

I have provisioned the Azure API Management service with Premium SKU and configured two regions

[image]

as per this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-api-management-update-february-2020/) we can now use the disableGateway property to disable API traffic in regional API gateways.

[image]

I have used REST API and updated the disableGateway property

[image]

however still I could access the regional URL.

How do I set the disableGateway to disable the **East** regional API gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disableGateway` property indicates that the API management's gateway (with URL https://myapim.azure-api.net for example) would not route traffic to the disabled region of the APIM instance. However if you use the regional URL directly (for example, https://myapim-eastus-01.regional.azure-api.net), it is still up and running like a passive instance and continue to have billing. True disabling would need you to [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region#-delete-an-api-management-service-location) the location from the APIM instance.

The article you referred, mentions:

> You can now use the disableGateway property to disable API traffic in regional API gateways. After adding a new region, you can initially keep it disabled to first configure and test the regional backend service.

It implies that only the traffic to it is disabled from the APIM gateway, you can still test with the direct URL of the regional endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Is there a way to set the property without using REST API? May be using cli or powershell?

Comment: az cli : `az apim update --name myAPIM --resource-group myResourceGroup --set additionalLocations[0].disableGateway=true` .  There might be powershell equivalent using [Set-AzApiManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagement).

Comment: How do I check which API gateway/region respond back while hitting the common URL eg: https://myapim.azure-api.net?

Comment: May some sort of header indicating the API gateway location?

Comment: If you [integrate with App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights), the telemetry would have 'Region' property in custom dimension automatically tracked.

Comment: Should I manually flush the DNS post disabling or enabling the regional gateway? I would be accessing https://myapim.azure-api.net by disabling the 2nd region and enabling the 1st region. In 2nd scenario, ? I would be accessing https://myapim.azure-api.net by enabling the 2nd region and disabling the 1st region

Comment: I don't think you need to flush DNS as it worked for me without that.